# Get distance v-rep proximity sensor Java

Tags: java, proximitysensor

I need to get distance in meters on a v-rep proximity sensor coded in `java`.

I can only know if it detects an obstacle or not, but not the distance

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have found to do this is to create a child script on the proximity sensor. In V-Rep, with the proximity sensor selected, go to `Add --> associated child script --> Non-Threaded`
then make the `sysCall_actuation()` look something like:

```
function sysCall_actuation()
    local name = sim.getObjectName(sim.getObjectAssociatedWithScript(sim.handle_self))
    result,distance,detectedPoint,detectedObjectHandle = sim.handleProximitySensor(sim.handle_self)
    if distance then
        sim.setFloatSignal("mydistance", distance);
    end
end
```

this reads the distance from the proximity sensor and pushes it to a signal (like a cross-platform variable type thing). Then on the java side have something like this:

```
    FloatW val = new FloatW(-1);
    vrep.simxGetFloatSignal(clientID, "mydistance", val, remoteApi.simx_opmode_buffer);//call this with simx_opmode_streaming once before this to start vrep streaming the distances
```

this gets the value sent from vrep and gives you the distance in the form of a FloatW.